# How can I print all common numbers in three inputted user arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

```java
int ar1, ar2, ar3;
System.out.print("Enter size of the 1st array: ");
//reading the number of elements from the that we want to enter  
ar1 = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter value of the 1st array: ");
for (int i = 0; i < ar1; i++) {
    array[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Array1: ");
for (int i = 0; i < ar1; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
}
```

What can I add to print the common numbers in three inputted numbers in arrays?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

first of all - arrays are primitive and quite a pain if it comes to using them. An alternative would be using ArrayList. But since you’re using arrays in this question, this would be an idea to solve the problem:
When your arrays are set up you can iterate through them to compare them. To do that you could declare 2 additional arrays:

```
int[] matchesA1A2 = new int[array1.length]; 
int[] matchesAll = new int[array1.length];
```

where *machesA1A2* will contain the values that are both in array1 and array2. And matchesAll ALL the matching numbers.
Now just iterate through the first array comparing it with the second one to find which values match. Like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i<array1.length; i++){
    for (int i2 = 0; i2<array2.length; i2++){
        if (array1[i]==array2[i2]){
            matchesA1A2[i] = array1[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The first two array are now compared. Now you can iterate through the third array comparing it witch the MATCHES of the array1 and array2 (which is the *matchA1A2* array). Like this:

```
for (int i3 = 0; i3<array3.length; i3++){
    for (int im = 0; im<matchesA1A2.length; im++){
        if (array3[i3]==matchesA1A2[im]){
            matchesAll[i3] = array3[i3];
        }
    }
}
```

If you println the *matchesAll* array you should see something, like this: [0, 0, 0, number, 0, 0, number, 0, 0…]

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matchesAll));
```

Alle the “numbers” in the array are values that match in all three arrays.

*Disclaimer: this is not the best way to write code, but I think because of the way it’s written it is easier for beginners to understand the concept of iterating.*

Comment: Well it doesn't work if the compared number is 0. This is an example of problems that you face using arrays ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: I can't find where I can add that to my code